# is $f$ a rotation?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f (z) = z + 2/z, z ∈ \mathbb{C}^{∗}$ . Then which of the following is/are true?

a) f is conformal

b) f maps unit circle to the real line

c) f maps circles to circles

d) f is actually a rotation .

a,b,c is false I have checked, but I am not able to tell what about d?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

Write in polar coordinates:

$$z=e^{it}\;,\;\;t\in[0,2\pi]\iff f(z)=e^{it}+2e^{-it}=3\cos t-i\sin t$$

Why is it enough to check on the unit circle?

Comment: I dont understand your hint so far...

Comment: If you have a complex element $\,z=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta\;$ , what does it mean you *rotate* it?

Comment: its angle get changed

Comment: Ok....if by "its angle" we agree to understand $\,\theta\,$, as above. Does this happen with your function?

Comment: No angle is remaining fixed as it was $t$

Comment: so none of the above statements is true?

Comment: Well @miosaki, if you already ruled out the first three ones...